# Proof that $P(A \cap B \mid C) \neq P(A \mid C) \, P(A \cap C)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I want to find a counterexample to verify that the following is false $$
P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid C) \, P(A \cap C)
$$
So I thought I would take $A=C$ and then
$$
P(A \cap B \mid C) = \frac{P(C \cap B)}{P(C)},
$$
and if, for example, $C \cap B = \varnothing$ with $C \neq \varnothing$, then
$$
P(A \cap B \mid C) = 0,
$$
but
$$
P(A \mid C) \, P(A \cap C) = P(A \cap C) \neq 0.
$$

Can this counterexample be useful? or is there a better one? thanks!

Comment: Instead of $C \ne \emptyset$ you should say $P(C) >0$. Otherwise, your example is fine.

Comment: How I approach this is note that RHS is independent of B, so we take advantage of that. Throw a dice, let its output random variable be $X \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. Then something trivial like $C = [X > 0]$, $A = [X > 0]$ and $B = [X = 0]$ works.